# Error with .eachLayer in leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping

I'm trying to add popups for point icons using Leaflet.js and ran into this error: "Uncaught TypeError: points.eachLayer is not a function"

Here's my code:

```
function addPoints(data){
    for (var feature in data.features){
        if(data.features[feature].properties.activity == "hunting"){   
            points = L.marker([data.features[feature].geometry.coordinates[1],data.features[feature].geometry.coordinates[0]], {
                icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                    'marker-color': '#FF5A5C',
                    'marker-symbol': 'bus'
                })
            }).addTo(map).on({
                mouseover: function(e){
                    this.openPopup();
                }, mouseout: function(e){
                    this.closePopup();
                }   
            });
        } 
    };
    drawPopup(data);
} //end addPoints
function drawPopup(data){
    points.eachLayer(function(layer){
        var popupContent = "Park: " + data.features[feature].properties.name + "<br />" + "Activities: " + data.features[feature].properties.activity; 
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    });
}
```

I've used nearly identical code before and have never run into this problem, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT 1:

You code with Layer Group would be like:

```js
var points = L.layerGroup();

addPoints(data);

function addPoints(data) {
    for (var feature in data.features) {
        if (data.features[feature].properties.activity == "hunting") {
            var marker = L.marker([
                data.features[feature].geometry.coordinates[1],
                data.features[feature].geometry.coordinates[0]
            ], {
                icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                    'marker-color': '#FF5A5C',
                        'marker-symbol': 'bus'
                })
            }).addTo(map).on({
                mouseover: function (e) {
                    this.openPopup();
                },
                mouseout: function (e) {
                    this.closePopup();
                }
            });

            // Keeping a reference to feature key.
            marker.feature = feature;
            // You could directly store all feature data into
            // the marker instead…

            // Finally adding the built marker into `points` Layer Group.
            points.addLayer(marker);
        }
    };
    drawPopup(data);
} //end addPoints

function drawPopup(data) {
    points.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        // Probably missing an assignment for `feature`?
        var feature = layer.feature;

        var popupContent =
            "Park: " +
            data.features[feature].properties.name +
            "<br />" + "Activities: " +
            data.features[feature].properties.activity;
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    });
}    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    });
}
```

As said in the comments, your code could probably be simplified by using [`L.geoJson` factory](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) rather than looping yourself through `data`. But it should do the job as is.

---

Your `points` variable looks to be only the last created marker:

`points = L.marker( ...`

You probably want to make a Layer Group (which has the `eachLayer` method) and add your markers into it:

```js
var points = L.layerGroup();

...
points.addLayer(L.marker(/* ... */));

...
points.eachLayer(function (layer) { /* ... */ })
```

Comment: That makes sense, but now I have the same error for points.addLayer "Uncaught TypeError: points.addLayer is not a function"

Comment: Most probable reason is that `points` is not properly initialized before using `addLayer`. Any chance you could reproduce your issue online? (e.g. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/18/)) You might also be interested in using `L.geoJson` to create your group with markers, rather than looping through the `data` yourself. In particular, you have the [`filter` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-filter) to select only the features that you want to keep.